# Setting IsUnicode to false for all types in Entity Framework Core 6

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

In normal Entity Framework you could use the code

`modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(c => c.IsUnicode(false));`

to set all created column times to a non-unicode version. I am working in EF Core 6 and trying to do this but `modelBuilder` does not have a `Properties` attribute and I am not finding any solutions that parting to EFCore 6 when searching around Has doing this universially been droped and I must specify it for every column now or is there a hidden method some where I am not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set all string properties to be non-unicode by default via pre-convention model configuration:

```cs
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping<string>(
        b => b.HasColumnType("varchar(max)").IsUnicode(false));
}
```

Alternative:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                 .SelectMany(e => e.GetProperties()
                     .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string))))
    {
        property.SetIsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```